# Web Service creation AWS

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services

So I am trying out AWS (Amazon Web Services) and I figured out how to put my db and its information on their server however I am not sure as to where I will put my php web service which gives a JSON response. Is there a tutorial or can someone tell me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: With the exception of a couple of elements, you would treat an aws instance like you would any other host.

Comment: @datasage with any other host I could just FTP my file and change the login information. Does AWS allow such?

Comment: Technically yes, but most instances don't set that up for you automatically. Making best use of AWS requires some system admin knowledge.

Comment: @datasage will look into it then may need to invest in some support

Comment: Amazon Elastic Beanstalk can make the deployment of your PHP service very easy

Comment: @Guy ok great now i know which service to look at

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are going to use the LAMP stack. I would either install LAMP on your EC2 instance or find a community image that has LAMP already installed and create an instance using that image.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with Amazon [Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/de/lightsail/) which is a beginner friendly service to deploy applications.

Or you can put your Application in Elastic Beanstalk and use its build in RDS feature for your database.
Attached you see the documentation for [deploying a PHP application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html).